# How to store split values into a Table

Tags: sql-server

I have an arraylist contains Id, ListId's values Listid's is a string contains multiple values with separated by comma like (101, 10,11,12,13). I want store this values into my table.
How would i achieve this.

```
insert into CompanyBillableAsset(Id, ListId)
     values(@Id, set @listId = select ListId from List where ListId in (select SplitValue from dbo.xf_StrSplit(@str, ',')))
```

Comment: In what language? What is the table schema? What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Please post you code Snippet you wrote

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql). Please do a basic search before posting a new question here. I found many answers using `[sql-server] split string` in a search here.

Comment: @KenWhite As I understand it, the question is not a duplicate, since the mentioned function `xf_StrSplit` seems to exist already. I'd assume it's a problem with the handling of the insert.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption your dbo.xf_StrSplit is working, your `INSERT` could look like:

```
INSERT into CompanyBillableAsset (Id, ListId)
SELECT @Id,ListId 
FROM List 
WHERE ListId in (select SplitValue from dbo.xf_StrSplit(@str, ','))
```